# Codeigniter : Batch Insert Array into DB

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having multi file upload in my codeigniter. I need to store the following values inside the database. I having the `file_name` as an array of 0,1,2 and so on(the maximum value depends upon the user's action), `folder_id`, `created` as fixed values.

For every `file_name`(0,1,2....), the `folder_id` & `created`, has to be inserted in the table

```
array (size=4)
  'file_name' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1.jpg' (length=5)
      1 => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
      2 => string '10_deepak.jpg' (length=13)
  'folder_id' => string '5' (length=1)
  'created' => string '2017-07-03 23:42:42' (length=19)
```

So Far, I have tried with the following;

```
$data = array(
             'file_name' => $data['file_name'] ,
             'created' => $data['created'] ,
             'folder_id' => $data['folder_id']
                );
         $this->db->insert('ins_files', $data);
```

For when i tried , I also got `Array to String` Conversion error too.

Comment: You can't pass in the data like that. You'll need to create a separate array for each file name.

Comment: ok how to get a separate array for each file name

Comment: You'll have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code. Here is the straightforward approach you can use like this.

```
$array = array(
    'file_name' => array(
      '1.jpg',
      '2.jpg',
      '10_deepak.jpg',
    ),
    'folder_id' => 5,
    'created' => '2017-07-03 23:42:42'
);
// encode the files name in Json array better 
// approach other you can also implode them to store

$data = array(
   'file_name' => json_encode($array['file_name']),
   'folder_id' => $array['folder_id'],
   'created' => $array['created'],
);
// Verify the data array
// echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
$this->db->insert('ins_files', $data);
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any more assistance. :)

Comment: Bro, It is saved like , all the data(`file_name`) are stored up in single row.. i want it to be saved for each `file_name` in separate rows. Each `file_name` to have `folder_id`,`created` [which is common for all rows]

Comment: Need some description of your problem